# Search specific info on internet and save it in a database

Tags: database

Is there a way to search specific information on the internet or on a search engine and save it in a database?

For example, you want to find all the Parties and their date in a specific region and save it in a database:

For example:

(id)
(Name)
(Date)

Is there a possibility to achieve this? Is there also a possibility to keep it up to date? If this is possible please let me know how.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, of course, it is possible. Use a programming language (C++, PHP, you name it) and a database (mysql, ms sql, oracle, whatever) and write a program that does it ;). Joking aside, you'd have to be a bit more specific. There is no short answer to your question (and nobody will write such a tool for you for free).

Comment: stop downvoting him!, it is just a question from someone wants to know somthing!

Comment: Yes, it is possible - Google, Bing, Yahoo etc all do it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't. 
start looking for somthing called [Web Crawler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler#Open-source_crawlers) to get specific info from a specific site.